# Clock generation in top level testbench

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The top level of my testbench looks like this:

```
module top();
    // `timescale 1ns/1ps

    reg_intf intfc(.clk(Clk));
    register_m dut (intfc);
    register_test_m (intfc);

    bit Clk = 0;
    initial 
    forever #1 Clk = ~Clk;
endmodule : top
```

`reg_intf` is an interface, `register_m` is design module,  `register_test_m` is a program (testbench).

I get this compile error:

> Net type cannot be used on the left side of this assignment.   The
>   offending expression is : Clk   Source info: Clk = (~Clk);

I tried using `logic`, `reg` and `wire` for `Clk` and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Move the declaration of `Clk` before its usage:

```
module top();
    // `timescale 1ns/1ps
    bit Clk = 0;

    reg_intf intfc(.clk(Clk));
    register_m dut (intfc);
    register_test_m (intfc);

    initial 
    forever #1 Clk = ~Clk;
endmodule : top
```

Unrelated to your problem: you need an instance name for register_test_m module:

```
register_test_m tb (intfc);
```

Comment: It should be noted that the reason you were getting that error was because `Clk` was getting implicitly declared as a wire, or net type, when it was first encountered in the port mapping.